# Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator not installing on my system

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

I want to make a simple windows phone 8 app. And I have installed on my pc:

```
OS : Windows 8 pro
Visual studio 2013 
SDK 8.0
```

And when I debug my app it give error below:

```
Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.
```

For resolving this error, when I an installing windows 8.1 Emulator it give me error below:

```
This computer does not support the windows phone emulator, which require the 64-bit edition of windows 8.1 Pro and a computer that support Hyper-v,
```

And my system type is `64-bit OS, x64-based processor.`

Kindly suggest me for resolving this issue, I am waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your computer support [Hyper-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) ? If it doesn't, then you can't run the emulator on your machine. According to the below Microsoft link,

> ```
> Your computer’s BIOS must support the following requirements, and they must be enabled:
>
> Hardware-assisted virtualization.
>
> Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
>
> Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP)."
> ```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#hyperv

Comment: Is there any way to debug my application without using emulator?

Comment: you will have to use a Windows Phone to debug your app without emulator. Even I had faced the same problem, the emulator won't work on my machine, used a phone and it worked perfectly.